# Single analogous word to "pedagogy" for learning

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy

Merriam-Webster defines pedagogy as "the art, science, or profession of teaching."

The concepts don't seem to map very well, but is there a word such that:

```
pedagogy : teaching :: _____ : learning
```

Comment: pedagogy : teaching :: pollywoggery : learning

Comment: Unfortunately not a single word:  "knowledge acquisition approach".

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be *[study](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/study)*

> The devotion of time and attention to acquiring knowledge on an academic subject, especially by means of books:
>
> *the study of English*
>
> *an application to continue full-time study*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Similarly *[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/study)*

> to apply the mind to the learning or understanding of (a subject), esp by reading:
>
> *to study languages*
>
> *to study all night*

Comment: Seems fair, it's just not as extravagant (or ostentatious) as "pedagogy".

Answer (score 3):

You may already have considered "[**scholarship**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scholarship)," a common synonym for "study" in the sense of

> serious formal study or research of a subject

from the Merriam-Webster online dictionary.